# Bash - Directory dependent script

Tags: bash, directory

I am trying to run a python script in a directory and using bash apply this script to each of its subdirectories.

I found a script on unix stack exchange that does it for 1 set of subdirectories [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171677/cd-into-all-directories-execute-command-on-files-in-that-directory-and-return) . But I want it to **recursively work for all sub-directories**.

The problem is I have a single `wav.py` in the parent directory but none in the sub-directories.

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && python3 $1 SA1.wav); done
```

As you can see $1 (wav.py) is the path to my python file set when I call the bash script. I would also like the path to be relative to how many levels of the subdirectory tree I have traversed. I know I can use an absolute path. But it will cause issues later on, so I'd like to avoid it.

Eg. for 1 level

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && python3 "../$1" SA1.wav); done
```

for 2 levels

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && python3 "../../$1" SA1.wav); done
```

Sorry if this seems trivial. I'm still new to bash.

**Additional Info:**

This is my full directory path:

```
root@Chiku-Y700:/mnt/e/Code/Python - WorkSpace/timit/TIMIT/TEST/DR1# bash recursive.sh wav.py suit rag
```

the full command I'm trying to run is:

```
python3 $1 SA1.wav $2 SA2.wav $3
```

$2 and $3 are unrelated to any directory info.

I get:

*python3: can't open file '/mnt/e/Code/Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory*

This error came 12 times for 11 subdirectories.

Comment: What's the problem in using the absolute path to your script?  If you are cd'ing to your subdirectories of arbitrary depth, deriving the relative path to your script can be quite cumbersome.  Also, it is not clear why you are traversing to the subdirectories.  Are you picking up any files from there?

Comment: I sometimes have whitespaces in my directory name. Those don't get parsed properly. and adding a '\' before the space doesn't help either. Also my subdirectories stop after a depth of 4-5

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to change the directory name from 'Python - Workspace' to 'Python-Workspace'. Like remove the space in the name and try it. That way you don't have to deal with the space in the script.
Secondly, can you tell what $1, $2, and $3 are. May be specify the complete script (without the variables) that you want to run, it gets easy for us to understand what you are looking for. 
Also I believe that when you cd into a directory you should be coming out to the directory where you started from, since you are giving relative path. You can try `cd -` to come back.

Comment: You may skip telling  $1, $2 and $3. I re-read your question and was able to get that $1 is wav.py. and $2, $3 are just the arguments to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your command, with wav.py being $1:

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && python3 $1 SA1.wav); done
```

Can we reduce the complexity by making wav.py executable and giving it a shebang, so that you can call it directly? Then you may move it to your PATH or temporarily putting the location, where it sits, into the path. It's generally best habit, that your script does not depend upon the place, from where it is invoked, especially that it isn't needed to be in the same directory from where it is called.

```
PATH=$PWD:$PATH
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && wav.py SA1.wav); done
```

The input data should not depend on the same directory restriction, so that you can call it from every dir and with the data being in an arbitrary dir, too:

```
for d in ./*/ ; do wav.py $d/SA1.wav; done
```

Probably, you produce an output file, which is written to the current directory, then you either should extract the output dir from the input dir, if this is what you always want to achieve, or let the user specify an output dir. A default outputdir might still be the inputdir or the current dir. Or you write to STDOUT, and pipe the output to a file, located to your choice.

But your full command is:

```
python3 $1 SA1.wav $2 SA2.wav $3
```

That's fine for simple commands, but maybe you can name these parameters in a meaningful way:

```
pyprog="$1"
samplerate="$2"
log="$3"

python3 $pyprog SA1.wav $samplerate SA2.wav $log
```

or, as done before

```
$pyprog SA1.wav "$samplerate" SA2.wav "$log"
```

Then, John1024s solution might work:

```
find . -type d -execdir $pyprog SA1.wav "$samplerate" SA2.wav "$log" ";"
```

If changing pyprog is not an option, there is a second approach to solve the problem:

Write a wrapper script, which takes the directory to work in as a parameter and test it with different depths of directories.

Then call that wrapper by find:

```
find . -type d -exec ./wrapper.sh {} ";"
```

The wrapper.sh should start with:

```
#/bin/bash
#
#
directory="$1"
```

and use it where needed.

Btw.: I would rename the `Python - WorkSpace` to `Python-WorkSpace` (even better: `python-workSpace`) too, because blanks in file and path names always cause trouble.